# Get current Python $base/bin ($base/Scripts) directory path

Tags: python

Is it somehow possible to programatically get the `bin`/`Scripts` directory path related to the current runtime environment? It's typically `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/bin` (or `C:\PythonXY\Scripts`), but it can be different in e.g. virtual environments.

I'm aware of the constants in `distutils.command.install`, but I hope there is an easier way to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

the virtual environment path is stored in the $VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable.

```
$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/Scripts
```

will give you what you want if you have a virtual environment loaded. you can check to see if that virtual environment is set, and if not, fall back on the system runtime directory:

```
if [ -z "$VARIABLE" ]
then
  dir=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/Scripts
else
  dir=/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/bin/Scripts
fi
```

another thing you can try is to extrapolate the runtime directory from the output of the command 'which python', which would give you something like this:

```
$(which python | cut -d "'" -f 3 | sed 's/python$//')"Scripts"
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it's not portable enough. It doesn't work on some other operating systems. I also hope that there is a function/variable giving the base name of the directory. However it seems that on Fedora Python scripts are installed into `/usr/bin`. I started to doubt there is a portable way.